# Why is the function addpos defined this way?

Tags: functional-programming, coq, theorem-proving

The following is the definition of the function addpos which defines addtition of a natural number to an integer. What is puzzling is the fact that here when n is matched with 0, addpos x2 0 gives succZ x2. Why cant it be just x2? Please explain.

```
Fixpoint addpos (x2 : Z) (n : nat) {struct n} : Z :=
  match n with
  | O ⇒ succZ x2
  | S n0 ⇒ succZ (addpos x2 n0)
  end.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that, given the name of the function, it is likely that this is intentional behavior. `addpos` means that we are adding a positive number; if we take "positive" to mean "strictly positive" (as, for instance, it is the case for the `positive` type in the standard library), then we see that the function is just using an element `n : nat` to represent the strictly positive number `S n`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why cant it be just x2?

It probably should be. Where did you get this definition from? I don't have `succZ` in my `Coq` install, so I had to change that to `Z.succ`. Then `Eval compute in (addpos 0 0)` yields `1%Z`, for example. Either the definition is wrong, or it is intended to add one more than `n`.

**EDIT:** Another answer suggests that it may indeed have been intended to add `S n`, and the definition accepts `n` as an encoding for `S n`. I think such an encoding should be made explicit, since it is easy to do so. For example, by defining a new type for positive integers with a single `OnePlus` constructor with a `nat` parameter.